# cmd, batch cd variable space excaping

Tags: batch-file, cmd, cd

So i was making a batch file for creating a folder with HTML content. The batch file basically executes a python file, and, as I'm going to make the batch file global, the python file runs with a parameter which is the directory I want to create the folder on.

The python file is working correctly because I've tested it many many times!

It works like this:

```
C:/Users/Tiago^ Oliveira/programming/python/random/HTML_Folder/HTML_Folder.py here_the_directory_we_want
```

and my batch file is like this:

```
C:/Users/Tiago^ Oliveira/programming/python/random/HTML_Folder/HTML_Folder.py %cd%
```

Whenever I execute the batch file in the `C:` drive it gets me this error:

> ```
> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] O sistema não conseguiu localizar o caminho especificado: 'C:\\Users\\Tiago\\html\\'
> ```

Which basically means the parameter is `C:\\Users\\Tiago` but in reality when I do `ECHO %cd%` it prints: `C:\Users\Tiago Oliveira\programming\python\random\HTML_Folder`, so this means there is a problem with my user name, *(which, BTW, I cannot change)*.

I've tried to replace the space between the names with the "^ " to escape the space and a lot of different options and I can't figure this thing out.

So I would like a little help for the ones that know what I can do to make this work.

Comment: Have you considered enclosing your file paths within doublequotes? Also I would usually advise that the `.py` file and its arguments are both passed as arguments to `python.exe`.

Comment: Yes i have already tried using the doublequotes

Comment: And what happened? because it's not just a guess, the existing answer says so, and I have been doing exactly that for tens or years without issue. How about you use the edit facility, and provide your tried codes too! You should tell us what you've tried, so that willing helpers do not tell you them again! Additionally, as you're running a `.py` file, it would assist us if you were also to provide the part of your code which accepts the input parameter, currently `%CD%` and preferably provide the fully qualified absolute path to your python executable too!

Comment: Did you know that StackOverFlow has a site specifically for your [language](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/)? Maybe they will be able to provide you with better assistance.

Comment: You are right @Compo it's my bad for not showing every detail i could but i still aprecciate the help! And sry for my bad formatting im not used to it yet :/.

Comment: @Squashman that's new for i didn't knew that exists! I'll definatly take a look at that, Thanks!

Comment: @TiagoOliveira it has been available for about 6 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path separator for cmd.exe is a REVERSE SOLIDUS (backslash).

No CARET is needed.

Paths need to use QUOTATION MARK characters.

```
"C:\Users\Tiago Oliveira\programming\python\random\HTML_Folder\HTML_Folder.py" "%cd%"
```

If this should always be under the current user's account directory, it would be better to use:

```
"%USERPROFILE%\programming\python\random\HTML_Folder\HTML_Folder.py" "%cd%"
```

Comment: I just arrived home and i tested it and it worked just perfectly, as im new to batch/cmd i didnt't knew u could do insert variables into strings like  `"%cd%"`, thanks a lot.